# Why is Heroku web app running so much slower than localhost for Flask?

Tags: sqlite, vue.js, flask, heroku

I'm building a basic web app that uses Vue + Flask + SQLite, and the app runs pretty quickly on localhost. Most of the data processing is done with pandas, and looking at the localhost logs, the data processing goes pretty quickly and thus loads the website very quickly as well. Once I deployed the website to Heroku, however, the data processing slowed down about 5x according to their logs. Does anyone know what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your PC has MUCH greater resources the heroku server.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types

Unless you're paying for a top dollar server, which I assume you're not.

Comment: For example, I've had task that run in 3 seconds locally take over 30 seconds on heroku so they time out. And that's while using the $50 standard-2x server.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not unique. From localhost to a commercial server, esp in the lower tiers, can slow down the app 2-3x.
However, in your case, 5x is a bit too much. The problem should be in your code. Also, would be great if you could mention any chunk of code that is slowing dramatically.
Here are a few things to improve:

1. Functions Improvement:
   Read about the time complexity of different functions. In general, avoid loops - for, while.
2. Database improvements:
   Make sure you are not fetching very large data all at once from the server. Do it in parts. Also, it is equally wrong to have the database queried for every small data chunk.
   One more point to note here is that instead of having a large chunk of data in one table and fetching small chunks from it multiple times. Split your tables.
3. Another common mistake is to save easily calculable values in the database. Avoid pushing data to the database for calculations. Keep them in the local environment or in the session.
4. I hope you are not moving or using files like CSV too much. Dataframes are faster.